# T-SQL: retrieve n times a specific number of rows where n is defined in an "IN" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, cursor

How can this query produce 20 results instead of 10?

```
SELECT TOP 10 colA, colB, colC
FROM table
WHERE id in (1, 2)
ORDER BY colA, colB
```

I would like to see 10 results for id equal to 1 and another 10 for id equal to 2. Do I have to use a cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you do not need to care about how many ids are in the `IN` clause.

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT colA, 
           colB, 
           colC,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY colA, colB) AS rn
    FROM   table 
    WHERE id in (1, 2) 
)
SELECT *
FROM   MyCTE 
WHERE  rn<= 10
ORDER BY colA, colB
```

Comment: You would probably want to use the same `ORDER BY` criteria in the `OVER` as the rest of the query - at the moment, you've changed it to "give me 10 random rows for each `ID` value and then sort them by `colA,colB` whereas the original query was "give me the 10 rows with the earliest/lowest `colA,colB` values"

Comment: I think you want "WHERE rn <= 10" not id*10, right? When you PARTITION by ID you get rn=1,2, ... for id=1, then rn=1,2,... for id=2, etc. In other words, if you partition by id, if you have 5 ids then you get rn=1 5 times.

Comment: @RobertSheahan Nope. OP says that he wants 10 for id = 1 and `another` 10 for id = 2. So 20 for id = 2.

Comment: @giannis-paraskevopoulos It's too big to fit in a comment, so I had to add an "answer", but check out the actual output of the 2 variations, you need to drop the id*

Comment: @RobertSheahan Reading through the OPs request i now tend to think you are right. I got it wrong, and i thought that for some reason he would want an increasing amount of results for each id. But your reasoning makes more sense. I am updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: I need to admit it seemed a bit awkward that the expected result would be 10*id rows...!!!! :-)

Comment: @Giannis-paraskevopoulos LOL, yeah, that's why I prefer SQL to English, it's not ambiguous :-) I had to read the question over several times too. Hopefully the OP will mark it as "accepted" to confirm (or comment as to why if he doesn't accept it).

Comment: @RobertSheahan The worse is that both the OP and I are from Greece and still lost in the translation...

Comment: Great stuff, it works, I read about CTEs to understand them, still don't get how this works though

Comment: You can think of CTEs as a pre-defined subquery. Instead of having `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table)` you define it at the top and use it in the next statement. in the CTE i am also defining the `ROW_NUMBER` which will give an incrementing number on each row for each id. This is what `PARTITION BY` does. So for each id, its first row will have number 1, the second row the number 2 and so on. Then i filter that selection to get only the rows which have less than 10 in their row number. That way we get top `X` for each group.

Comment: Ευτυχώς κατάλαβες τι έγραφα στα Αγγλικα στο προηγούμενο σχόλιο, γιατί ήταν πολλά κι εγώ δυσκολεύτηκα...!!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `union all` will help you

```
SELECT TOP 10 colA, colB, colC FROM table WHERE id = 1
union all
SELECT TOP 10 colA, colB, colC FROM table WHERE id = 2 
ORDER BY colA, colB
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER (but it's too big to fit in a comment)
@Giannis, here is your code with sample data. I changed 10 to 3 to save some space.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT, colA int, colB int)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1,10,20), (2, 30, 40), (1,14,23), (2, 32, 45), (1,16,28), (2, 35, 42), (1,11,27), (2, 34, 41), (1,19,23), (2, 32, 48), (1,17,26), (2, 37, 42)

;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT id, colA, 
           colB,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY colA, colB) AS rn
    FROM   @T
    WHERE id in (1, 2) 
)
SELECT *
FROM   MyCTE 
WHERE  rn<= id*3
ORDER BY colA, colB
```

Here are the results
id  colA    colB    rn
1   10  20  1
1   11  27  2
1   14  23  3
2   30  40  1
2   32  45  2
2   32  48  3
2   34  41  4
2   35  42  5
2   37  42  6

Notice that the id*3 gives rn<= 6 when id=2

If you modify your WHERE to rn <= 3 you get the following.
id  colA    colB    rn
1   10  20  1
1   11  27  2
1   14  23  3
2   30  40  1
2   32  45  2
2   32  48  3

which is what the OP asked for